# Hebrews, Muslims and Biblical men

Tags: wordplay, rhyme, knowledge

> The first among Hebrews, a beverage of barley,
>   the first among Muslims, a city with Ali,
>   share a relationship which is the same
>   as a Biblical man's English and Spanish name.

Who is the Biblical figure?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A topical pop

> Joseph

The first among Hebrews, a beverage of barley,

> aleph - first letter of the Hebrew alphabet, ale - brew of barley.

the first among Muslims, a city with Ali,

> Caliph - leader of the Muslim world, Cali - major Columbian city (also C + ali).

share a relationship which is the same, as a Biblical man's English and Spanish name.

> Removing the final ph from Joseph gives José.

Comment: rot13(nyvs vf gur svefg yrggre bs gur nenovp nycunorg)?

Comment: Yep, all correct! Nice work.